# go append is weird when loop map

Tags: go

I am encountering golang weird behaviour when I try too loop map(with array as key). You can reproduce it via go playground.

https://play.golang.org/p/GNVBJTpoR98

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    m := make(map[[2]int]bool, 0)
    m[[2]int{1, 2}] = true
    m[[2]int{1, 3}] = true

    res := make([][]int, 0)

    for ke, _ := range m {
        res = append(res, ke[:])
    }

    fmt.Println(res)    
    // expect: [[1 2] [1 3]]
    // actual: [[1 3] [1 3]]


}
```

Is this a golang bug ?

Comment: Assign `ke` to a temporary variable inside the loop. eg: `tmp := ke; res = append(res, tmp[:])`. The iterator variables are reused through the loop, you need to make a copy if you want to keep the values.

Comment: See https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-reference-to-loop-iterator-variable for more details.

Comment: Whoever has voted to close this question, bear in mind that this is not "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". This is an entirely valid question and makes perfect sense, as this scenario may be very confusing for many.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug, this is expected behaviour. Variable `ke` was defined for your loop once and then in every iteration it keeps the reference of the *current* map key. When you append its slice to `res`, you use the reference of `ke`, which at the end of the loop is referring to the last key of the map.

The solution is to create a new reference as a temporary variable inside the loop:

```golang
for ke, _ := range m {
    v := ke
    res = append(res, v[:])
}
```

Check the official documentation for more details (thanks to [@Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471131/go-append-is-weird-when-loop-map/63471381#comment112236665_63471131) for the link): https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-reference-to-loop-iterator-variable